# Interpreting Results of Repeated Measures - Shift calculation in plots

Tags: plotting

What would be a more accurate method to calculate the shift in waveform (waveform drift) from a collection of 20 or more data plots.

Current method, Plot all using Show and see if there is some distinctive shifts. But since the change in plots is very minute, how can I get a more accurate value for the shifts ?

[Example data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byj8JxXAeyj_bFdBa3lEMm4zOHc/view?usp=sharing)

My idea is something like below:

[image: Example Image]

Comment: I'm not sure if its the best way but you could just compute the shift for every point and average? I would guess this would be very precise since you are sampling many points

Comment: I gave a thought to that idea, but resorted to this assuming that the shifts can be seen and also a calculated value can be given

Comment: `ListConvolve` might prove useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the data

```
{a, b, c} = 
  Transpose@
   Rest@Import[
     "Example_Data.csv", 
     "Data"];
```

And you can let Mathematica find it by integrating the difference with a shift,

```
FindMinimum[
 NIntegrate[
  Abs[
   Interpolation[b, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x]
    - Interpolation[c, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x - s]
   ], {x, Min[a], Max[a]}]
 , {s, 0}]
```

> ```
> {4543.82, {s -> 0.00914418}}
> ```

You can get a visual idea where the minimum is and its quality (Beware these is computationally intensive).

```
Plot[
 NIntegrate[
  Abs[
   Interpolation[b, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x]
    - Interpolation[c, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x - s]
   ], {x, Min[a], Max[a]}]
 , {s, -0.1, 0.1}]
```

> [image]

Comment: This is computationally intensive method,but very accurate.

Comment: @abhilashsukumari There are [things to do after your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), but don't rush, you may want stay vigilant some time after you get the first answers as its likely that the best approaches may come later improving over a previous reply. Therefore, its a good idea to wait two days before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the deserving answers and [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you. (Links contain useful information). :)

Answer (score 4):

[`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCorrelate.html)is useful as well.

Let's make some sample data

```
Block[{\[Omega]0 = 1/2},
 t0 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1/25]] + 
     Sinc[\[Omega]0 (# - 50)] & /@ Range[0, 100, 1/4];
 t1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1/25]] + 
     Sinc[\[Omega]0 (# - 52)] & /@ Range[0, 100, 1/4];
 ]

ListLinePlot[{t0, t1}, PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {0, 100}]
```

[image]

Use `ListCorrelate` (with maximal overhang to the right and zero padding to avoid circular correlation).  Now look for the argmax (I interpolated, but it's not needed).

```
ListLinePlot[ListCorrelate[t0, t1, {1, 1}, 0], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
f = ListInterpolation[ListCorrelate[t0, t1, {1, 1}, 0], Range[0, 100, 1/4]];
ArgMax[{f[t], t > 0}, t]
(* 1.99011 *)
```

Comment: Couldn't get your code to work on my data. Please do try it on the Example data in question.

Comment: would the question be any different, if I were to ask - how much does the two list differ if we were to compare amplitude values (assuming there is no shift on time scale) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can plot the two curves with a shift defined as a Manipulate variable.

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[{
   Transpose[{measureX + shift, measureY}],
   Transpose[{controllerX,      controllerY}]
   }],

 {{shift, 0}, -0.3, 0.3}
]
```

Initial plot with a shift of zero

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and now shifted by -0.15. You can type in the value as accurately as your eye is able to view.

[image: Mathematica graphics]